# Cannot Find Object in Data Environment

Tags: r, dataframe, assign

I have a table with a list of names which I used to programmatically assign to subsets of a large data table.  As you can see, some of them contain spaces.

```
inputs$Equity.Country.Names

 [1] "AUSTRALIA"     "AUSTRIA"       "BELGIUM"       "BRITAIN"       "CANADA"        "DENMARK"      
 [7] "FINLAND"       "FRANCE"        "GERMANY"       "GREECE"        "IRELAND"       "ITALY"        
[13] "JAPAN"         "NETHERLANDS"   "NORWAY"        "PORTUGAL"      "SPAIN"         "SWEDEN"       
[19] "SWITZERLAND"   "UNITED STATES" "NEW ZEALAND"   "ARGENTINA"     "BRAZIL"        "CHILE"        
[25] "CZECH"         "HONG KONG"     "INDONESIA"     "ISRAEL"        "MALAYSIA"      "MEXICO"       
[31] "PHILIPPINES"   "POLAND"        "SINGAPORE"     "SOUTH AFRICA"  "SOUTH KOREA"   "TAIWAN"       
[37] "THAILAND"      "TURKEY"
```

I used this loop to do the assignment, and received no errors.  The names with no spaces in them seem to work, I can call them from the console.  Furthermore, in my Rstudio "Environment" tab, object names that do have spaces in them are shown, and when I view them, there is data.  However, if I try to call the object from the console, as expected I cannot.  I am confused about why I was able to make any kind of assignment in the first place.

```
for (i in 1:NROW(inputs))
{
  assign(inputs$Equity.Country.Names[[i]], subset(bdata, ticker == inputs$Equity.Tickers[[i]]))
}
```

Also, I realized the mistake I had made when I tried to run this loop:

```
for (i in 1:NROW(inputs))
{
  assign(paste0("nona",inputs$Equity.Country.Names[[i]]), na.omit(eval(parse(text = inputs$Equity.Country.Names[[i]]))))
}
```

And then got this error, which I believe is because of the space issue, United States is the first name in the list which contains a space.

```
Error in parse(text = inputs$Equity.Country.Names[[i]]) : 
  <text>:1:8: unexpected symbol
1: UNITED STATES
```

are these objects whose names have spaces actually in memory and why?  can I still refer to them?

Comment: Try putting back-ticks around the names with spaces in them when you go to call them

Comment: But in general, object names with spaces are a bad idea.  You could first remove the spaces from all the names with `gsub(" ", "", inputs$Equity.Country.Names)` and then you won't need backticks at all

Comment: Thanks Richard.  yes I understand that they are a bad idea, what I am wondering is why I didn't return an error with the first loop.  And why do I see the object UNITED STATES in the "global environment" in my Rstudio, and with data in it?  Why only the second loop returned an error?